# I need to find the distribution of data, which is from a retail chain network. No distribution fits the data

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit, joint-distribution

[image]I need to find the distribution of data, which is from a retail chain network( demand of product across all stores). I tried to fit distribution using EasyFit (which has 82 distribution to check the best distributions) but no distribution fits the data. What can be done? Is there any way to find if the data distribution is a sum or convolution of multiple distribution? I have removed the spikes or seasonality or promotional data from the dataset but still no distribution fits. I am attaching the histogram of the data. The problem lie with tails as its not decreasing smoothly.

Comment: I want to know if there is any method to find data distribution is combination or convolution of multiple distribution.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the distribution?  Non-parametric methods will provide a density, CDF and other properties without explicitly defining a distribution, but their usefulness is a function of what you actually want to do with the data.

Comment: I want to generate the demand from this distribution (i.e from the data). This demand will be used in my simulation model. Can you provide me more information on the non-parametric methods. @JonathanLisic

Comment: Why would you expect that it would be one of a list of 82 distributions? You might look at mixtures, or you could look at simulation from say a kde. What does the distribution look like?

Comment: @Glen_b I want to look at the mixtures or sum of distribution but how to do it. Is there any tool or any methods? My data distribution is close to gen pareto or johnson sb or extrme value.. But the test statistics (KS and anderson darling) rejects it. I need some kind of mixture or sum of distribution. whats kde?

Comment: I take it that you'd be happy to use any distribution that didn't get rejected by a goodness of fit test and unhappy to use any that was rejected? Why is that your criterion? kde == kernel density estimate ...  What properties do you want this simulation to have?

Comment: @Glen_b Actually all the distribution have been rejected. The closest distribution that resembled the shape was gen pareto and johnson sb. But goodness of fit test rejects them too. I need to find the demand distribution from the given data. As all of the standard distribution has been rejected by goodness of fit test (KS and anderson darling) I am confused on which distribution to be used. kde or non parametric distribution can be used I suppose. Just want to know if there is any tool which can show if the data distribution is sum of two distribution.

Comment: I understand that all the short list of distributions was rejected; I was questioning the rationale behind your earlier actions. I think there's an issue there that still hasn't been adequately discussed.

Comment: @Glen_b I need to simulate a retail chain network model for which I need the demand distribution. I have the past demand data of the retail stores. I need to find a distribution that fits this demand data so that I can use that distribution to generate the demand in the model. Now I am confused on how to generate those demands as I cannot use any standard distribution (Need to have logic or support for using any specific distribution).

Comment: Even if you could regard historical demand as an iid sample from your target distribution (which I seriously doubt), you only have a sample -- you simply can't get at "the distribution" of demand.  What properties do you want this simulated distribution to have? What kind of justification do you need? How is demand measured (is it a count or a dollar amount or something else)? What does (say) log(demand) look like? There are several possibilities discussed in a variety of answers to questions here, but what might be suitable depends on information we don't seem to have right now.

Comment: @Glen_b The demand is the count of the product, i.e number of items sold per day. By justification I mean that the distribution should have some credibility(a distribution which failed the KS and anderson darling test is not acceptable). See the demand in the google sheets. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b1urdAxy3EsqpBKEyD9_d5qgZei4bna7nUR1raBBgoY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: 1) you have count data -- any continuous distribution should be rejected by a decent test.    2) Why would rejection by a goodness of fit test make the distribution unacceptable? What is the reasoning?   3) With a sufficiently large sample, any simple distribution will be rejected.  4) if "only distributions which aren't rejected by goodness of fit tests" are acceptable, then just sample from the ECDF.

Comment: @Glen_b Actually I did sample it. I tried fitting distribution with data of one product one store. Also one product one day ALL stores. Again it did not fit any discrete distribution except for continuous (gen pareto). I dont know the answer for your question (2). But I have been asked to use distribution that fits the data.

Comment: With regard to 'fits the data" -- rejection by a goodness of fit test doesn't imply a bad fit at all; it might represent a trivial difference with a large sample size. Closeness of fit is an effect-size, while a p-value from a goodness of fit test is not. You might consider something more like an equivalence test. If you must use a goodness of fit test, I think the empirical distribution of the data is probably the best choice (the data obviously fits itself). Outside of that, a mixture of perhaps 2-3 negative binomials or of about 4 Poisson and geometric components might do okay.

Comment: @Glen_b I was thinking on the same lines regarding the mixture of Poisson or negative binomial. Is there any method or tools to find out the mixture of such distribution or is it trial and error?

Comment: Among other possibilities, you can use MLE or moment matching. (It's a problem that frequently has difficulties however - there are various issues with identifiability for example) -- many packages offer functions to do it. With MLE, the EM algorithm is a standard tool. There's some discussion of mixture models and estimation (Cosmo Shalizi's notes), [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch20.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I would start with nonparametric bootstrapping. This technique will not assume any distribution, it will simply sample from the empirical distribution. There are tricks and traps in using this technique, of course, but in your situation it could be the best first shot.

Obviously, you should not stop at bootstrapping. One thing to do is to look at conditional distribution. Your plot shows unconditional distribution, i.e. you lumped all observations together regardless of their place in time or relation to the factor that might have affected the observations such as the state of economy, holidays, promotional campaigns and advertising spending. When you take these factors into account, and build conditional distribution you may get a very different picture.

For instance, you could suspect that the sales $S_i$ are dependent on promotional events $P_i$ and regional unemployment $U_i$ at a given store. So, you regress the model $S_i=\beta_p P_i+\beta_u U_i +\varepsilon_i$. Now, you look at the distribution of $\varepsilon_i$, which is going to be the conditional distribution. In simulation though, you'll have to come up with simulated values of $P$ and $U$ and the random error to them in order to produce the simulated sales $S$.

Comment: I have removed the promotional effect from the data. Can you please provide good source or material on nonparametric and conditional distribution. Only factor here is the time. Pls take a look at the data below. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b1urdAxy3EsqpBKEyD9_d5qgZei4bna7nUR1raBBgoY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am simulating store level activity in my simulation model. For this model I need a daily demand which can be generated from distribution. The problem is as you can see in histogram that curve is not decreasing smoothly at the tail (Main reason that no distribution fits this data). So I just need to generate the demand using some distribution which fits this data. I was thinking whether this can be represented by the sum of two distributions? Otherwise nonparametric or empirical distribution will be the only option. @aksakal

Comment: Google nonparametric bootstrapping, I don't have a favorite resource, since I mostly use parametric, but here's one link that seems to be clearly written http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/LargeSample/notes/notebootstrap.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I will see if bootstrapping or kernal methods work. Can you try to fit distribution on the data given in the link if possible by your method or tools. I have used excel addon easyfit and Minitab. @aksakal